# Finding 'glitch' primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Consider numbers of the form
$$
p=\underbrace{b\,\cdots\, b}_{n\,b\text{'s}}\,a\,\underbrace{b\,\cdots\, b}_{n\,b\text{'s}},
$$
where $0\leq a\leq 9$ and $1\leq b\leq 9$. In other words,
$$
p=(a - b)10^n +\frac{b}{9}(10^{2 n - 1} - 1).
$$
For example, $121,44344$ and $9990999$ are numbers of this form.

Given $a$ and $b$, for which values of $n$ is $p$ prime? Clearly, $p$ can only be prime if $b\in\{1,3,7,9\}$. What else can we say?

Letting $m=2n+1$ be the integer length of $p$, and just for fun, here are some of the values of $(a,b)$ and $m$ for which $p$ is a prime number (up to numbers of integer length $1000$)
\begin{matrix}
a&b&m\\
0    &   1  &    \{  3     \}\\
1    &   1  &    \{ 9, 23, 317, 1031      \}\\
2    &   1  &    \{       \}\\
3    &   1  &    \{ 3, 5, 39, 195      \}\\
4    &   1  &    \{ 5, 7, 65, 91      \}\\
5    &   1  &    \{   3, 15, 91, 231, 1363    \}\\
6    &   1  &    \{  21, 29, 81, 119, 321, 825, 1121     \}\\
7    &   1  &    \{ 7, 67, 623      \}\\
8    &   1  &    \{ 3 , 9, 13, 15, 769, 1333, 1351     \}\\
9    &   1  &    \{  3, 9, 53, 375, 453, 1749     \}\\
0    &   3  &    \{       \}\\
1    &   3  &    \{  3, 7, 15, 123, 181, 185, 539, 597, 643, 743, 1553     \}\\
2    &   3  &    \{       \}\\
4    &   3  &    \{       \}\\
5    &   3  &    \{ 3, 5, 35, 159, 237, 325, 355, 371, 481, 1649      \}\\
6    &   3  &    \{       \}\\
7    &   3  &    \{   3, 7, 15, 23, 27, 35, 59, 63, 67, 155, 1867    \}\\
8    &   3  &    \{  3, 15, 171, 189, 547, 713     \}\\
9    &   3  &    \{       \}\\
0    &   7  &    \{       \}\\
1    &   7  &    \{  233     \}\\
2    &   7  &    \{3, 7, 15, 21, 25, 961, 1899       \}\\
3    &   7  &    \{ 5      \}\\
4    &   7  &    \{   5, 7, 13, 47, 73, 139, 1123, 1447    \}\\
5    &   7  &    \{ 3, 15, 27, 117, 259, 507      \}\\
6    &   7  &    \{ 9, 11, 17, 23      \}\\
8    &   7  &    \{  3, 7, 79, 109, 337, 481     \}\\
9    &   7  &    \{  3, 5, 17, 39, 41, 425, 561, 1775     \}\\
0    &   9  &    \{       \}\\
1    &   9  &    \{ 3, 11, 27, 87, 339, 363      \}\\
2    &   9  &    \{  3, 17, 19, 705, 1061, 1395     \}\\
3    &   9  &    \{       \}\\
4    &   9  &    \{  29, 45, 73, 209     \}\\
5    &   9  &    \{ 177, 225, 397, 1245      \}\\
6    &   9  &    \{       \}\\
7    &   9  &    \{ 237      \}\\
8    &   9  &    \{  53, 757     \}
\end{matrix}
For example, for $a=4$ and $b=7$, $7777774777777$ is prime.

Naturally such answer entirely depends on the given pair $(a,b)$, but I wonder if something can be said about specific cases. For example, for which cases does $m$ take infinitely many values?

PS - If these type of primes are known, please suggest me a better name than the title.

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=HPfAnX5blO0

Comment: base the number is in affects a lot as well.

Comment: It will be hopeless to decide for any pair of digits whether infinite many primes exist , if we cannot rule out a prime like in the case of the pair $(3/9)$.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee The question only seems to be about such primes in the usual base $10$. What is this video about ? Is a survey of primes of that form given ?

Comment: glitch primes from numberphile, it also visits the base 2 case, where exactly 1 exists.

Comment: If we are just dealing with the base 10 case, here are a few things:

 $$b\equiv 1\bmod 3\implies a\not\equiv n\bmod 3$$
 $$b\equiv 0\bmod 3\implies a\not\equiv 0\bmod 3$$
 $$n\equiv 0\bmod 6\implies a\not\equiv 0\bmod 7$$

Comment: The expression for the numbers is $$\frac{b\cdot 10^{2n+1}+9a\cdot 10^n-9b\cdot 10^n-b}{9}$$

Comment: Thanks @Peter, I'll edit my question to add this.

Comment: OEIS refers to these as palindromic wing primes: http://oeis.org/A077798. See also http://www.worldofnumbers.com/wing.htm